# Bash script with using special characters in variable array and copy to folder

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, variables

I've a new question about a closed question from me.
In the last one I asked for help in fixing a script, which sorts files to folders by it's content. ([Bash script which sorts files to folders by it's content; How to solve wildcard in variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283535/bash-script-which-sorts-files-to-folders-by-its-content-how-to-solve-wildcard))

Now I have a new problem with that.
The variables had changed. The old ones where single word variables in an array, now I've multiple words with special characters as variable.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a standorte;                               
standorte=('Zweigst: 00' 'Zweigst: 03' 'Zweigst: 08')

ls lp.3.* | while read f
do
for ort in "${standorte[@]}"; do
   grep -i $ort "$f" >/dev/null 2>&1
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo Copying $f to $ort
      cp "$f" $ort
   fi
done
done
```

Now you see, the "ort" is the folder name. So the script try to copy the file lp.3.* to e.g. Zweigst: 00. But without the escape backslashes it doesn't work. Put I escape charakters into the variable, the script doesn't work, because in the file lp.3.* is no "Zweigst:\ 00".

I think, I must declare a new variable for "ort" where I put the folder names in it.
But I've no idea how to change the for loop. I must say the script, when you found Zweigst: 00 copy this file to folder "zweigst00". I'm sorry my bash script experience is not good at all. I can't change this by my own.

I have multiple (zero to unlimited) lp.3.* files (e.g. lp.3.1, lp.3.2, lp.3.5.2 and so on)
In this files is this text: http://pastebin.com/0ZzCUrpx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to quote the variable:

```
for ort in "${standorte[@]}"; do
   grep -i "$ort" "$f" >/dev/null 2>&1
#          ^----^-------- quotes needed
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo Copying $f to $ort
      cp "$f" "$ort"
#             ^----^-------- quotes needed
   fi
done
```

Why? Because otherwise this

```
grep -i $ort "$f" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

gets expanded as something that `grep` cannot understand properly:

```
grep -i Zweigst: 00 "$f" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

see that it is trying to grep `Zgeigst:` from file `00`.

Comment: I tried this out and it works, when I rename the folder. The "00" or "03" is the indicator for the correct folder and file. But it't not tragic that it gives me this output? http://pastebin.com/yeaY71p2

Comment: Mmmm I think you should also quote in `cp` ---> `cp "$f" "$ort"` to make it copy properly. I also update my answer.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot! I thought I must change so much, but that it is this easy, I can't believe. :)

Comment: It's checked! Thank you and have a nice weekend.

Comment: Instead of `>/dev/null 2>&1` you can do `&>/dev/null`.